# Add Copy of VS Project Folder as Branch to VSTS Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a team that edited a Visual Studio project saved on a network drive. Whenever they'd publish to LIVE, they'd copy that folder and increase the number after it before working on new features (so the old, working version was there to fall back to if needed).

I've pushed the last working version to VSTS as MAIN branch via Git. Now I'd like to push the latest in-progress version to VSTS as a branch. Is there an easier way to do this than copy-pasting the code of the changed project files while working in the branch of the working solution?

Comment: Don’t use git as a deployment strategy. Look into continuous integration. VSTS has significant features regarding CI.

Comment: I worded that poorly. It's an MVC website that gets published to the web server in Visual Studio. I am trying to move the project and its features to VSTS so no more of this folder-copying-versioning takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your process sounds about right.

- Create a `master` branch from the last known-good version.
- Commit it.
- Create a `develop` branch from that.
- Robocopy (or otherwise synchronize) the current development version into the repo (you want to pick up deleted/added files as well as modified files)
- Commit it

Then you're good to go.

Kudos to you for implementing version control, by the way. I can't fathom how a team successfully delivers software without using version control in this day and age.